# How To Install A Windows Service In .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, installation

I have created a console application in .Net 2.0 (C#) and want to create an installer that will install the application as a Windows Service.

I have never created an installer before but I am reading a few articles on the subject. I would appreciate any suggestions or links from those with some experience in this area.

Thanks.

UPDATE: I am currently looking at http://justinjmoses.wordpress.com/2008/03/27/visual-studio-2008-standard-vs-professional/ to work around the fact that the Windows Service Application template is not included in VS 2008 Standard.

Russ Taylor also has a default Windows Service project available for download at http://russtaylor.co.uk/2009/01/writing-a-windows-service-in-visual-studio-2008-standard/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a new "Windows Service Project" in Visual Studio.

I think this is a good starting point:

> [Introduction to Windows Service Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Apparently, the Windows Service Application Template is not available in the standard edition of Visual Studio, but maybe this can help:

> [How to: Write Services Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76477d2t.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. It says the Service App template is not available in the Standard Edition of VS (which I have). Can this template be install manually. Is it necessary to use a Service template? Will a Console App not work?

Comment: @modernzombie: You can create a service programmatically, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want `ServiceInstall` in WiX: http://www.tentaclesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/01/01/21.aspx